# OkHttp SSL handshake aborted in Android

Tags: android, ssl, https, okhttp, tls1.2

One of my app went live last week. And almost 10-20% of app users are receiving SSL handshake aborted Error when they try to communicate with our servers. Other 80% users are fine and they can connect, also during testing phase we didn't notice these errors on our testing devices.

Application is using OkHttp 2.5.0 (latest) also okio 1.6.0 (latest)

Full stacktrace -

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x64e7c010: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(NativeCrypto.java)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:426)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
```

Crashlytics show this is happening on Android 4.3+. This needs to be fixed as 10-20% users are really too much in our app's case.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1209. The post suggests that your cipher suites are out of date on your servers. Is it just Apache with ordinary SSL certificates?

Comment: If so consider throwing away old ciphers [according to this](https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/) and testing [with this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) - I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Also find out the difference in installed ciphers on failing/successful handsets (or is this happening with _all_ 4.3 handsets?)

Comment: Also see the GitHub link for another approach, which is to disable certain ciphers on the Android end.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hey, @halfer thanks for the help, I forwarded these details to my server guy and he will look into it. btw, I have tested it on genymotion 4.3, but its working also, crashlytics shows that not all 4.3+ handsets have problems.

Comment: @halfer also, can you explain "disable certain ciphers on the Android end" in more details?

Comment: I cannot explain in more detail, no - I do not develop for Android. See the link in the GitHub link I supplied - I just did some search-engine searching for you.

Comment: @rohit, no, Jesse was asking if _you_ have reproduced the problem, on your own test handset. You will need to do this to see if you have fixed it.

Comment: oh sorry for that, no we couldn't reproduce this issue.

Comment: @halfer we are using nginx with latest ciphers

Comment: You'll need to obtain a handset that actually fails here before you can go on, I think. Maybe try setting up a test server and disable ciphers one by one until you get a failure? This is tricky because it may be handset/version dependent, so there are a lot of variables to satisfy to reproduce it. That said, if 10-20% of your users experience it, it cannot be that rare...

Comment: Have you worked out what the crashing handsets have in common? I would have thought Crashlytics would help you there. (Rhetorical question - I won't be able to assist further. Good luck.)

Comment: ok, so its been 1 and half month and still no answer. We have been analysing the errors and there is SSLHandshake aborted as well, so I think okHttp is falling back to SSLv3 and our servers doesn't support SSLv3. So what can we do to disable SSLv3 so that okHttp won't use it.